# Error: I can click under the navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-layout, android-navigation

I have a bug in my application and I dont know how to solve it. My application has two navigation drawer, right and left. The right navigation drawer works well but when the left navigation drawer is open and I click within it, it detect that I'm clicking in the main layout. In order to understand better I show you this picture:

[image]

I hope I explained well.

This is my code:

- layout.

  ```
  <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  <FrameLayout
      android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="0" />

  <!-- Left -->

  <ListView
      android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
      android:layout_width="400dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_gravity="start"
      android:background="@color/black_main"
      android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
      android:divider="#555555"
      android:dividerHeight="1dp"
      android:listSelector="@drawable/menu_list_selector" />

  <!-- Right -->

  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/right_drawer"
      android:layout_width="400dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_gravity="end"
      android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
      android:background="@color/white_opaque"
      android:orientation="vertical" >

      <LinearLayout
          android:id="@+id/container_filtros"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical" >

          <LinearLayout
              android:id="@+id/cnt_filtros"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical" >

              <include
                  android:id="@+id/filtros"
                  layout="@layout/menu_filtros" />
          </LinearLayout>

          <LinearLayout
              android:id="@+id/cnt_categorias"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:visibility="gone" >

              <include
                  android:id="@+id/lstCategorias"
                  layout="@layout/filter_categorias" />
          </LinearLayout>
      </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>

  </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
  ```
- Java code:

  ```
  private void setSlides(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
  mDrawerViewRight = (View) findViewById(R.id.right_drawer);
  mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
  mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

  mFilterList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_filter);
  mRightDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.right_drawer_list);
  mOrdenarList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_ordenar);
  mDistanceList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_distance);

  // LEFT SLIDING
  navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<MoNavMenu>();

  // Items
  navDrawerItems.add(new MoNavMenu("DIIN", R.drawable.slide_img_home));
  navDrawerItems.add(new MoNavMenu("¿QUÉ HACER", R.drawable.slide_img_quehacer));
  navDrawerItems.add(new MoNavMenu("¿A DÓNDE IR?", R.drawable.slide_img_dondeir));
  navDrawerItems.add(new MoNavMenu("DESCUBRE", R.drawable.slide_img_descubre));
  navDrawerItems.add(new MoNavMenu("LEE TU MAPA", R.drawable.slide_img_leermapa));
  navDrawerItems.add(new MoNavMenu("CAPTURA DIIN", R.drawable.slide_img_captura));
  navDrawerItems.add(new MoNavMenu());
  navDrawerItems.add(new MoNavMenu("CONFIGURACIÓN", R.drawable.slide_img_config));

  // RIGHT SLIDING
  navRightDrawerItems = new ArrayList<MoNavCategory>();
  navFilters = new ArrayList<MoNavFilter>();
  navFilters.add(new MoNavFilter("CATEGORÍA", filterCategoria));


  adapter = new AdNavMenu(getApplicationContext(), navDrawerItems);
  adapterR = new AdNavRight(this, navRightDrawerItems);
  adapterFilter = new AdFilterHome(this, navFilters);

  mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
  mFilterList.setAdapter(adapterFilter);
  mRightDrawerList.setAdapter(adapterR);
  getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
  getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

  mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
          R.drawable.ic_drawer, 
          R.string.app_name, 
          R.string.app_name 
          ) {
      public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
          getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
          invalidateOptionsMenu();
      }

      public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
          getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
          invalidateOptionsMenu();
      }
  };
  mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

  if (savedInstanceState == null) {
      displayView(0);
  }
  }
  ```

Comment: You have framelayout for right drawer so it will transfer your click to bottom widget if your top widget is not consuming that user click. So you need to add empty view and set onclick listener and consume click there. Button will not get click any more.

Comment: Thank you so much. I add a empty onClick method to a LinearLayout and now it works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have framelayout for right drawer so it will transfer your click to bottom widget if your top widget is not consuming that user click. So you need to add empty view and set onclick listener and consume click there. Button will not get click any more.

Answer (score 10):

You have to write `android:clickable="true"` in your sliding pane layout.