# Cannot click on item's view inside RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to show a `popup menu` for each item of a `RecyclerView` when a button is clicked.

**My Adapter:**

```
public class SearchResultRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchResultRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>  {

    public SearchResultRecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<BookModel> bookModels, Context context) {
        this.bookModels = bookModels;
        this.context = context;
    }

    ArrayList<BookModel> bookModels;
    Context context;


    @NonNull
    @NotNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_book,parent,false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Log.d("aa", bookModels.get(position).getThumbnailLink());

        Glide.with(context)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(bookModels.get(position).getThumbnailLink())
                .into(holder.coverImage);

        holder.name.setText(bookModels.get(position).getName());

        holder.author.setText(bookModels.get(position).getAuthor());
        holder.category.setText(bookModels.get(position).getCategories().toString());
        holder.maturity.setText(bookModels.get(position).getMaturityRating());
        holder.desc.setText(bookModels.get(position).getDesc());

        holder.option.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { ///////////// here
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //show popup
                Log.d("ItemOption","Clicked");
            }
        });


        if (position+1 == bookModels.size()){
            holder.divider.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return bookModels.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        RoundedImageView coverImage;
        TextView name;
        TextView author;
        TextView desc;
        TextView category;
        TextView maturity;
        ImageView divider;
        Button option;
        RelativeLayout root;


        public ViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            coverImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cover_book_item_imageview);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_book_item_textview);
            author = itemView.findViewById(R.id.author_book_item_textview);
            desc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.desc_book_item_textview);
            category = itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_book_item_textview);
            maturity = itemView.findViewById(R.id.maturity_book_item_textview);
            divider = itemView.findViewById(R.id.divider_book_item_imageview);
            option = itemView.findViewById(R.id.option_book_item_button);
            root = itemView.findViewById(R.id.root);
        }


    }
}
```

**My item Layout:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cover_book_item_cardview"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_81sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_124sdp"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_15sdp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_8sdp"
        android:elevation="@dimen/_5sdp">
        <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
            android:id="@+id/cover_book_item_imageview"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:src="@drawable/testcover"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:riv_corner_radius="@dimen/_5sdp"/>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/name_book_item_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="name"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/cover_book_item_cardview"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_90sdp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/yanonekaffeesatz_medium"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/cover_book_item_cardview"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_90sdp"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_18sdp"
        android:textColor="@color/light_black"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/author_book_item_textview"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_13sdp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/yanonekaffeesatz_medium"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_1sdp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name_book_item_textview"
        android:text="author"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/cover_book_item_cardview"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_90sdp"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/cover_book_item_cardview"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_90sdp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/desc_book_item_textview"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_190sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
        android:layout_below="@id/name_book_item_textview"
        android:width="@dimen/_60sdp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/cover_book_item_cardview"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_90sdp"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/cover_book_item_cardview"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_90sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_30sdp"
        android:textColor="@color/light_black"
        android:text="desc"
        android:fontFamily="@font/yanonekaffeesatz_medium"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/holder_book_item_linearlayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@id/name_book_item_textview"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/cover_book_item_cardview"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_90sdp"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/cover_book_item_cardview"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_90sdp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/category_book_item_textview"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:fontFamily="@font/yanonekaffeesatz_medium"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_rectangle_90"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/yellow"
            android:padding="@dimen/_3sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_72sdp"
            android:text="category"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/maturity_book_item_textview"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:fontFamily="@font/yanonekaffeesatz_medium"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_rectangle_90"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/light_black"
            android:padding="@dimen/_3sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_72sdp"
            android:text="maturity"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5sdp"/>
    </LinearLayout>


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/option_book_item_button"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_more"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/light_black"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/cover_book_item_cardview"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_260sdp"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/cover_book_item_cardview"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_260sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_23sdp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/divider_book_item_imageview"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_200sdp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#DFDFDF"
        android:layout_below="@id/holder_book_item_linearlayout"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_15sdp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Initializing RecyclerView:**

```
recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.search_result_recyclerview);
recyclerView.scheduleLayoutAnimation();
recyclerView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Log.d("CheckRecyclerView","clicked");
    }
});
searchResultRecyclerViewAdapter = new SearchResultRecyclerViewAdapter(bookModels,SearchActivity.this);
recyclerView.setAdapter(searchResultRecyclerViewAdapter);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(SearchActivity.this));
    }
```

**XML Layout of Activity:**

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawerlayout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">



    <RelativeLayout

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

   <!--
      Views
      -->
       <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/appbar_cardview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/search_result_recyclerview"
            android:layoutAnimation="@anim/search_result_recyclerview_anim"
            android:visibility="gone"/> <!-- will become visible later-->
    <!--
      Views
      -->
    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView

        app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_main" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

when the item's view is clicked nothing happens. I've done the same exact thing before with no problem I don't know what I'm missing here.

**EDIT:**

as @anemomylos mentioned this might be a click issue. in this layout there is a lot of `Views` that will be `Gone` in order to `RecyclerView` shows up. RecyclerViews don't register any clicks themselves so I'm not sure if it's being blocked by another view or not, is there any way to know what is blocking the click? I don't have any `android:clickable="true"` and I made sure that all `Views` before `RecyclerView` are `Gone` and not `Invisible`

Comment: Is the line Log.d("ItemOption","Clicked"); printing ?

Comment: Remove _android:onClick="optionMenu"_ from xml file for _Button_

Comment: @gioravered no its not

Comment: @Piyush i removed it but nothing changed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create Options Menu for RecyclerView-Item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37601346/create-options-menu-for-recyclerview-item)

Comment: @javdromero no because onClickListener doesn't work in my case

Comment: It might be useful to add the code where is declared the RecyclerView, the Adapter and also the portion of the xml file.

Comment: Could be a click issue like in this case? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22373073/error-i-can-click-under-the-navigation-drawer/30030457